# how to crosscut a method from parent class?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Parent class:

```
public class Animal {
  public String name() {
    return "my name";
  }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  // no methods
}
```

I'm trying to crosscut a call to `Dog.name()` with AspectJ, but doesn't work:

```
@Aspect
public class Crosscut {
  @Around("execution(* Dog.name())")
  public Object exec(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
    // this point is never reached
  }
}
```

However, if I add a child method to the `Dog` class, the crosscut works:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  public String name() {
    return super.name();
  }
}
```

How to write the right crosscut? Or it's not possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since aspectj does not create a new method here it will not be able to match `Dog.name()`.
What you need to do is declare the advice on `Animal.name()` and use `this(...)` to make aspectj add a runtime instanceof check.

Try 
`@Around("execution(* Animal.name()) && this(Dog)")`

Answer (score 1):

Actually jontro's idea is good, but the solution is simpler in case you are not fixated on `Dog`, but want to intercept all `name()` methods on `Animal` and its subclasses:

```
@Around("execution(* Animal+.name())")
```

Comment: thanks, can I use `*+.name()` to match all classes with method `name()`?

Comment: In this case you do not need the plus sign. ;-)